# MATLAB: Construct matrix from selected matrix elements

Tags: matlab

I have a 3x3x3 matrix which contains a particular set of elements that I would like to extract. However, I would like for the elements to be ordered in a matrix after selecting them. An example is:

```
a(1,:,:)=1*[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
a(2,:,:)=2*[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
a(3,:,:)=3*[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];

a(a>1.0)
```

The condition `a(a>1.0)` gives me a vector of elements, but is there a way to order them in a matrix following their original ordering?

Comment: How are you defining their "original" ordering? Wanting an arbitrary matrix isn't going to work, matrices have to be rectangular and there's no way for you to guarantee this.

Comment: Doing `a(a > 1.0)` will return a vector in column major order, meaning that the elements returned will be such that any values that satisfy this condition will be read from `A` by sweeping from top to bottom, left to right, then going into each slice still maintaining that order.  If this is not the ordering you desire, edit your post to explicitly state what order you want these to appear as.

Comment: are you looking for `(a>1.0).*a`?

Answer (score 0):

What would you like to do to the elements that don't satisfy your criteria?

You could do something like `a(a<=1) = nan;`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose 2-D matrix for simplicity:

```
a = [1 2 3; ...
     4 5 6];
```

Let's take only *even* values and keep them in their *original* shape:

```
a(mod(a, 2) == 0)
```

You might want:

```
  2
4   6
```

However, in the world of matrix, is there such a matrix which has *empty* space? Yes, a sparse matrix. But, you must note that a sparse matrix is filled with *0* not just missing.

So, my suggestion is to replace other values with `NaN`

```
b = a; % just make a duplicate
b(mod(b, 2) == 1) = nan
b =
    nan    2    nan
      4  nan      6
```